# Redirect Image URL to it's parent post

Tags: redirect

I am trying to redirect my image URL to its parent post (where an image has been used).

For example: Image URL is `example.com/04/2020/image.jpg`
and it was used on `example.com/post/my-post`

I had tried Yoast, Rank math etc but neither of them help me.

Is there any possibility to achieve this no matter if it's a plugin or `.htaccess` file?

Please remember it's an image not an attachment page or something.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for posting! Does it have to be the raw image file, or can you link to the attachment page in WordPress? If you could give the reason why you need this redirect, we may be able to offer alternative solutions.

Comment: It's a raw image not wordpress attachment. i want every image should redirected to it's parent post.

Comment: If `/04/2020/image.jpg` is the URL you are currently using, what is the URL that you want this redirected to?

Comment: https://crewrocks.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Crew-Rocks-300x300.png this is image and here is parent Post URL where this image was used https://crewrocks.xyz/2020/04/29/attachment-redirect/ so if user land on https://crewrocks.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/Crew-Rocks-300x300.png it should redirect to parent post https://crewrocks.xyz/2020/04/29/attachment-redirect/  This should work for all post

Comment: But if that image is actually being used on the page then you can't _reliably_ differentiate between legitimate requests when the image is displayed within a page and direct requests that you want to redirect. In theory, you can check the HTTP `Referer` header, however, this is _unreliable_ - some users will not see your image.

Comment: MrWhite: Did you get the solution to this?

Comment: You would also need to fundamentally change the front-controller pattern in `.htaccess` to route all static image requests through WordPress (normally they are explicitly excluded), since only WP could _possibly_ know the parent page URL for an arbitrary image (if indeed this information is stored or can be calculated somehow). (But what if an image is used on more than one page?) So, this redirect could only be performed in WordPress itself, not `.htaccess`, unless you are OK with hardcoding every redirect. Consequently this could potentially slow down your WP site significantly.

Comment: I didn't ask the question. However, any generic (any image / any post) solution would be horribly inefficient and unreliable at best. See my last two comments on the question.